# porque mi codigo no funciona? Python

Tags: python-3.x, condiciones

Hola soy nuevo en phyton y estaba experimentando pero me encontre con este problema. Yo creo que lo escribi bien pero no sale bien.

```py
print('Introduce tus datos.')
email=input('Email: ')
password=int(input('Contraseña de 4 digitos: '))

email_check=False
password_check=False

if '@' and '.com' in email:
    email_check=True
    print('Email correcto.')
else:
    print('Email incorrecto')

if password in range(1000,10000):
    password_check=True
    print('Contraseña correcta.')
else:
    print('Contraseña incorrecta')
```

Si no hay un .com en el email no funciona pero si falta el arroba si que funciona a pesar de que eso debe comprobarse en el if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el primer condicional, analizamos la línea:

```
if '@' and '.com' in email:
```

si agregamos paréntesis en función del orden de evaluación de la expresión veremos más claro lo que ocurre:

```
if (('@') and ('.com' in email)):
```

hay que tener en cuenta que el operador `in` tiene preferencia sobre `and`, por lo que no es `if (('@' and '.com') in email)`, lo cual sería incorrecto de todas formas.

a la hora de evaluar lo primero es obtener el resultado del "y" lógico (`and`):

- Se evalúa si el primer operando es verdadero (`'@'`), lo cual siempre es cierto porque **toda cadena no vacía en Python es evaluada como `True`**.
- Como el primer operando es evaluado como verdadero se evalúa el segundo, la expresión `'.com' in email`. El cual será `True` o `False` dependiendo si `'.com'` está o no en la cadena `email`.

Cómo resultado nunca se evalúa si "@" está o no en la cadena, la linea anterior es lo mismo que `if '.com' in email:` realmente, dado que el primer operando es siempre verdadero.

Para comprobar si ambas subcadenas están en `email` debes hacer:

```
if '@' in email and '.com' in email:
```

Si quisieras comprobar la existencia simultánea de más subcadenas, el condicional puede hacerse muy largo e incluso poco legible. En tal caso, puedes recurrir a `all` y un iterable con las subcadenas a comprobar:

```
subs = ("@", ".com")

if all(sub in email for sub in subs):
    email_check = True
```

Ten en cuenta que no es un método muy fiable de validar si un email tiene el formato correcto, `."comfulanito@"` sería validado, ya que validas que contenga `".com"` y `"@"`, no dónde.

Comment: Gracias. comento que me funciona la version de las subcadenas, ya que la version de comprobar ambas por separado me daba el mismo resultado. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Hola Yabel, ¿con que valor de email `if '@' in email and '.com' in email:` no te da el resultado esperado?